Can I use coefplot to plot scalars made with estadd?
I have scalars that I added to estimates store with estadd that appear in a table I made with estout. I now want a coefficient plot of those scalars (which include an adjusted coefficient and adjusted confidence intervals), not the unadjusted coefficients. These scalars appear when I run ereturn list, but the coefplot command yields empty plots when I include these scalars in the keep() portion of the coefplot command.
I have tried several ways of inputting the scalars into the keep command, including e(nameofscalar) and nameofscalar as well as different formats of the coefplot command, but coefplot will only plot elements like coefficients, not these added scalars.

I'd take this to Statalist. More people who use coefplot hang out there than do here, and the author of coefplot watches that site and is not known by me to visit this. As an SO question this suffers from the lack of a reproducible example. coefplot is an excellent command, but I don't use it.
